# Flow based on an Objects History

Tags: visual-workflow, workflow, history-tracking, field-history, process-automation

Is it possible to build a flow based on an objects history. For instance, if I wanted a fields to update whenever another field is changed by one specific user. How would I go about this I cannot seem to find a good solution.

Comment: Does it have to run in real-time? Or can it run later on a schedule?

Answer (score 0):

Flows can now be created to launch when a record is created or edited (no more Process Builder needed). So you can make one of the entry criteria be when that record was edited by a particular user.

[image]

If you're using a sandbox, you should not hardcode the ID like I did here (even without sandboxes probably don't do it that way). Instead you should do a lookup element before this, find the user ID based on name, and then use the ID found there in place here.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you question then this is what i would've done .
you have couple parts in your question

1. update fields
2. update them when other field is changed.
3. update them when specific user does the update
4. you need 2 and 3 to work together for 1 to update

now im assuming there are no decisions.
the record trigger is:
name of field is changed true
AND
user who modified it equals id number

after that you can use update element and update the fields .

this way only when something changed and is changed by X user it will update other fields.

and again its by what you explained this is what i would've done

Comment: It would be good if you would clarify about what salesforce automation tool you are talking about, you can also add pictures to more clarify your point.